# Wrong mediatype between directshow filters

Tags: directshow, video-capture, media-type, fmle

I've developed a capture filter in DirectShow to send images from a cam to FMLE. To test it I send RGB 24b blue samples which can be correctly seen on GraphEdit or GraphStudio, whereas in FMLE they take an strage color (I show you this in image below). I think it's problem of mediatype negotiation, but I'm stuck. Which would be my next steps to correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely media type negotiation. Adobe FMLE is not a nicely behaving video capture application implementing video capture accurately to support a wide range of devices. Instead, it assumes the device is a web camera, having support for resolutions of interest and pixel formats. Don't be surprised if it ignores error codes your filler returns on some calls.

> Which would be my next steps to correct this?

Your next step is to trace all incoming calls to get an idea what FMLE is expecting from you. Then you will have to update your filter respectively. For instance, the application might require that you support specific resolution, and you might need to resize on your end instead of insisting on resolution you support and suggest.